# SoapUI override properites value of testCase when run as test step

Tags: properties, soapui, testcase

I have a test case that use custom properties. I want to override the properties value with another value when i run this testcase as a test step in another test case. how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the Return Properties to those custom properties (same name) in your Run TestCase Options then it should be overriding those values.

Comment: i want the parent test case will override the original values of the test session